# Where does SmatArt font come from

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

When I insert custom SmartArt, where does the font family come from? Can I change the font family if I have the SmartArt selected?

Answer (score 0):

The default font comes from the font theme (part of the presentation theme, though you can select a different font theme from the design tab).  To change the font via code:

```
Sub ChangeSmartArtFont()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSmartArt As SmartArt
    Dim x As Long

    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    If oSh.HasSmartArt Then
        Set oSmartArt = oSh.SmartArt
        With oSmartArt
            For x = 1 To .Nodes.Count
                With .Nodes(x).TextFrame2
                    .TextRange.Font.Name = "Algerian"
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```